# Why does sp_columns / sys.spt_columns_odbc_view return incorrect results?

Tags: sql-server

While investigating a question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221302/sp-columns-typename-data-type-vs-table-designer-ntext-vs-nvarcharmax), I discovered that `sp_columns`, which uses `sys.spt_columns_odbc_view`, is returning the *wrong / unexpected* `DATA_TYPE` & `TYPE_NAME` for `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. It's returning `NTEXT` for `NVARCHAR` columns and I can't figure out why. Does anyone have any insight?

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/FIBP77392)**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[deleteTable](
    [v] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [t] [ntext] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

select 
    c.name
    ,c.system_type_id
    ,ty.name
    ,ty.precision
    ,t.name
from 
    sys.columns c
inner join 
    sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
inner join 
    sys.types ty on ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
where
t.name = 'deleteTable'

exec sp_columns @table_name = 'deleteTable'
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: I've tested on 2012 and 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why you get `NTEXT` but do not know why this is done. This note may be relevant:

> sp_datatype_info is equivalent to SQLGetTypeInfo in ODBC. The results
>   returned are ordered by DATA_TYPE and then by how closely the data
>   type maps to the corresponding ODBC SQL data type.

In the definition of `sys.spt_columns_odbc_view` there is a piece of code:

```
TYPE_NAME = CONVERT(sysname, 
CASE 
WHEN ( 
    t.system_type_id = 240 
    OR 
    t.user_type_id > 255 
  ) 
  THEN -- CLR UDTs 
  t.NAME 
  ELSE d.type_name COLLATE database_default 
END 
), sys.types t ON ( 
  t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id 
) 
INNER JOIN sys.spt_datatype_info d ON ( 
  d.ss_dtype = c.system_type_id 
  AND 
  d.auto_increment = c.is_identity 
)
```

In your case `ELSE d.type_name COLLATE database_default` this is being executed because the data type is -10.

`sys.spt_datatype_info` uses [sp_datatype_info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-datatype-info-transact-sql).

If you execute below code you will see where `NTEXT` is coming from.

```
EXEC sp_datatype_info -10;  
GO
```

[image]